# Swift - Not able to hide or unhide UIView considering I can see it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a two-file project for a podcast player application. My goal is when the user clicks the Play Button (loaded in nib cell), there will be shown PodcastPlayerView (added to StoryBoard in View Controller) with play/pause.

```
.
├── _DetailViewController.swift
│   ├── AVPlayer
│   ├── PodcastPlayerView  (full-screen player view)  
│   └── setupPodcastPlayer (setting player's URL & hide/unhide PodcastPlayerView)
│
├── _PodcastViewCell.swift (File Owner of the nib)
│   ├── url (Podcast URL of the cell)
└── └── @IBAction playPodcast (the play button in a cell)
```

This is the most of the code runs in the PodcastViewCell.swift. Gets the cell's itemId, finds its podcast link, then passes it to the View Controller.

```swift
protocol PodcastViewCellDelegate {
    func podcastButtonClicked(podcastUrl: String)
}

class PodcastViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var delegate: PodcastViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func playPodcast(_ sender: Any) {
         if let itemOffset = allItems?.itemListv2.firstIndex(where: {$0.itemId == itemAuthor?.itemId}) {
            podcastLink = allItems?.itemListv2[itemOffset].podcastsound
         }
        
         let url = podcastLink ?? " "
         delegate?.podcastButtonClicked(podcastUrl: URL)
     }
}
```

This is the View Controller code that contains Podcast Player UIView, AVPlayer Player, Collection View for PodcastViewCells, etc. I also added the lines where I can and can't hide/unhide PodcastPlayerView in the code. When I run the application while the view is unhidden, the view is visible and stands where it should be. But I still can't unhide it in the line where I mentioned it. It's like the view loads and gets destroyed...

```swift
class DetailViewController: BaseViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var podcastPlayerView: UIView!

    var podcastLink: String = ""
    static var itemId = "0"

    var player: AVPlayer?
    var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
    var timeObserverToken: Any?
    var played = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.podcastPlayerView.isHidden = false "<-------- Unhiding/hiding process successful in this step"
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        showPodcastButton = false
        player?.pause()
        player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        player = nil
    }
    func setupPodcastPlayer(link: String) {
        player?.pause()
        player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        player = nil
        if !played {
            if link != "" {
                playerItem = AVPlayerItem( url:NSURL( string:link )! as URL )
                player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)

                player!.rate = 1.0;
                player!.play()

                played = true
                podcastPlay()
            } else {
                "link empty"
            }
        } else {
            player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
            played = false
        }
    }
    func podcastPlay() {
         self.podcastPlayerView.isHidden = false "<---- If I try to unhide here, app crashes."
    "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
    }
}

extension DetailViewController: PodcastViewCellDelegate {
    func podcastButtonClicked(podcastUrl: String) {
        podcastPlayerView.isHidden = false
        setupPodcastPlayer(link: podcastUrl)
    }
}
```

Thank you for any advice and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here

```
DetailViewController().setupPodcastPlayer(link: url)
```

This `DetailViewController()` is a new instance not the presented one , hook the real shown one and change it's attribute as needed through delegate or a notification if you need to

**Edit:** inside cell

```
weak var delegate: DetailViewController?
```

and set it in `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Then what should I do is pass the URL with a delegate and THEN change the visibility of the view, right?

Comment: I have updated the code with delegate changes. This time my player stopped playing at all I think because the setupPodcastPlayer just doesn't run at all.

Comment: Add breakpoints and track your code as expected  BTW this is another problem your question is now answered

Comment: Did `cell.delegate = self` ??  inside `cellForRowAt` ?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and was just fixing it. That was the passing problem. The delegate method worked perfectly, thank you for your effort!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem but in a reverse direction. I want to reload WebView in PodcastViewCell while "viewWillDisappear" executing in DetailViewController but I get nil for WebView. Any tips for this? Do delegates work for this too? I didn't want to create another question for the nearly same problem.